# Rails: Bad Interpreter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler, interpreter

I've recently faced this problem in rails. Almost every code I've entered return an error, saying there's a bad interpreter. The following are some of the errors I've been facing lately:

**bundle install**

> sh exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/bundle: "c:/Program:
>   bad interpreter: No such file or directory

**rake db:migrate**

> sh exe": /c/Program Files (x86)/ruby-1.9.3/bin/rake: "c:/Program: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Even my reinstalling rails multiple times, I'm unable to solve this error.

Comment: Try re-installing to a path that doesn't have spaces or any sort of funky char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it doesn't like the space in the path ...

Can you reinstall everything in a path without spaces? It usually is safer

Comment: Yup! You can also add quotes to the current path in the environment variables! Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION:**

There shouldn't be spaces in the path name. To solve this, you can either:

**1)** Add quotes (" ") to your path. 
Example is as follows:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.3\bin` will become `"C:\Program Files (x86)\ruby-1.9.3\bin"`

**2)** Reinstall in a new non-spacing path